# Minecraft too many logins / blacklisted IP help?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been having a problem for the last 15-16 hours now where the game will refuse to let me play due to a "blacklisted IP or too many logins." However, I was told that this ban would last at most 1 to 4 hours from other sources. Is there any way I can get the login to work? Nothing also happens when I try to login on minecraft.net.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried repeatedly for those 15 hours without any pause of over 4 hours? I would recommend waiting 4 hours without making any login attempt and then trying again. If that doesn't work, contact customer support.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you're on a shared IP network (like a School/College/Work network) or even a small network (siblings sharing the same IP) and multiple users have triggered an internal ban to the network.

If that's the case, you'll need to ensure all users do not make a login request for the next 4 hours, or if you can't control access via all users, speak to Customer Support to advise them that this is a Shared IP. Most online service providers are able to verify the mac addresses and IP address and make it exempt from this type of ban, whilst switching to an alternate method of capturing abuse.

Comment: You can't verify the MAC address, because the MAC never leaves your local network.